# VSO MSBuild: The given path's format is not supported

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I am trying to setup CI on a solution containing 60 projects. I keep getting the following error message on only four of them:

> 2018-04-17T18:55:08.4252401Z GenerateMsdeployManifestFiles:
>
> 2018-04-17T18:55:08.4252401Z Generate source manifest file for Web Deploy package/publish ...
>
> 2018-04-17T18:55:08.4282049Z ##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing\ImportAfter\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3507,5): Error : The given path's format is not supported.
>
> 2018-04-17T18:55:08.4282049Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing\ImportAfter\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3507,5): error : The given path's format is not supported. [D:_Work\7\s\src\Feature\Code[Repo]\MyProject.csproj]
>
> 2018-04-17T18:55:08.4411480Z Done Building Project "D:_Work\7\s\src\Feature\Code[Repo]\MyProject.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Line 3507 in the Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets file is this:

> ```
> <ExportManifestFile Manifests="@(MsDeploySourceManifest)" ManifestFile="$(PackageSourceManifest)" />
> ```

The odd thing is this issue is only happening for some projects, not all. I tried to compare them but I didn't see anything obvious.

We are able to build the full solution on our local environments using visual studio. I have also installed visual studio on the CI server and was able to build the solution there as well.

Comment: Use the developer command prompt and make sure the version of MSBuild you choose lines up with the CI server.  Visual Studio builds are not equivalent to the CI server builds.  Fix the issues that arise from the cmd line build.

Comment: What's the failed build projects, it's website projects or web projects? And it's mainly caused the project types are different in the solution file. And can you show the detail logs by setting system.debug as true?

Comment: Is this your local path for the project? D:_Work\7\s\src\Feature\Code[Repo]\MyProject.csproj. Note the 'Code[Repo]'. Is this is it, remove the [] from the path. Please let me know.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT all of the affected projects are ASP.NET Web Application projects.

Comment: @RodrigoWerlang the [Repo] is just a placeholder for the post, I don't want to identify the client, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue. I went through the installed programs on the CI server and saw that visual studio 2015 and 2017 were both installed. I uninstalled both of them and reinstalled VS2017 - it is now building successfully.